# Unable to retrieve views by using Resource Id in xamarins Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am developing an Android and iOS application using Xamarin.Forms. I am a complete beginner to Xamarin. In my application, I am trying to create a custom camera view. So, I know that I have to develop the custom camera view specific to each platform using content page renderer feature.

First, I am trying to implement the camera feature for the Android first. When I create the custom camera page, I need to set the layout and retrieve some views using resource id from my code. But when I retrieve views referencing to resource id in Android project. It is not working.

In the main Xamarin forms project, I created a view page for Camera and like this. This is the XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MementoApp.Views.CameraPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the xaml.cs

```
namespace MementoApp.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CameraPage : ContentPage
    {
        public CameraPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the Android project, I created a new axml layout file under Resource folder called Camera.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
  <TextureView
      android:id="@+id/textureView"
      android:layout_marginTop="-95dp"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/toggleFlashButton"
      android:layout_width="37dp"
      android:layout_height="37dp"
      android:layout_gravity="top|left"
      android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
      android:background="@drawable/NoFlashButton" />
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/switchCameraButton"
      android:layout_width="35dp"
      android:layout_height="26dp"
      android:layout_gravity="top|right"
      android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
      android:background="@drawable/ToggleCameraButton" />
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/takePhotoButton"
      android:layout_width="65dp"
      android:layout_height="65dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
      android:background="@drawable/TakePhotoButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the full code of my CameraPageRenderer class in Android project

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CameraPage), typeof(CameraPageRenderer))]
namespace MementoApp.Droid
{
    public class CameraPageRenderer: PageRenderer ,TextureView.ISurfaceTextureListener
    {
        Android.Hardware.Camera camera;
        global::Android.Widget.Button takePhotoButton;
        global::Android.Widget.Button toggleFlashButton;
        global::Android.Widget.Button switchCameraButton;
        global::Android.Views.View view;

        Activity activity;
        CameraFacing cameraType;
        TextureView textureView;
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture;

        bool flashOn;

        public CameraPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            this.activity = context as Activity;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                SetupUserInterface();
                SetupEventHandlers();
                AddView(view);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"           ERROR: ", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        void SetupUserInterface()
        {
            activity = this.Context as Activity;
            view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Camera, this, false);
            cameraType = CameraFacing.Back;

            textureView = view.FindViewById<TextureView>(Resource.Id.textureView);
            textureView.SurfaceTextureListener = this;
        }

        void SetupEventHandlers()
        {
            takePhotoButton = view.FindViewById<global::Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.takePhotoButton);
            takePhotoButton.Click += TakePhotoButtonTapped;

            switchCameraButton = view.FindViewById<global::Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.switchCameraButton);
            switchCameraButton.Click += SwitchCameraButtonTapped;

            toggleFlashButton = view.FindViewById<global::Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.toggleFlashButton);
            toggleFlashButton.Click += ToggleFlashButtonTapped;
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

            var msw = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(r - l, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);
            var msh = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(b - t, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly);

            view.Measure(msw, msh);
            view.Layout(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
        }

        public void OnSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface)
        {

        }

        public void OnSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
        {
            camera = global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Open((int)cameraType);
            textureView.LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
            surfaceTexture = surface;

            camera.SetPreviewTexture(surface);
            PrepareAndStartCamera();
        }

        public bool OnSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface)
        {
            camera.StopPreview();
            camera.Release();
            return true;
        }

        public void OnSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height)
        {
            PrepareAndStartCamera();
        }

        void PrepareAndStartCamera()
        {
            camera.StopPreview();

            var display = activity.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay;
            if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0)
            {
                camera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
            }

            if (display.Rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270)
            {
                camera.SetDisplayOrientation(180);
            }

            camera.StartPreview();
        }

        void ToggleFlashButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            flashOn = !flashOn;
            if (flashOn)
            {
                if (cameraType == CameraFacing.Back)
                {
                    toggleFlashButton.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.FlashButton);
                    cameraType = CameraFacing.Back;

                    camera.StopPreview();
                    camera.Release();
                    camera = global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Open((int)cameraType);
                    var parameters = camera.GetParameters();
                    parameters.FlashMode = global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FlashModeTorch;
                    camera.SetParameters(parameters);
                    camera.SetPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
                    PrepareAndStartCamera();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                toggleFlashButton.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.NoFlashButton);
                camera.StopPreview();
                camera.Release();

                camera = global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Open((int)cameraType);
                var parameters = camera.GetParameters();
                parameters.FlashMode = global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters.FlashModeOff;
                camera.SetParameters(parameters);
                camera.SetPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
                PrepareAndStartCamera();
            }
        }

        void SwitchCameraButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cameraType == CameraFacing.Front)
            {
                cameraType = CameraFacing.Back;

                camera.StopPreview();
                camera.Release();
                camera = global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Open((int)cameraType);
                camera.SetPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
                PrepareAndStartCamera();
            }
            else
            {
                cameraType = CameraFacing.Front;

                camera.StopPreview();
                camera.Release();
                camera = global::Android.Hardware.Camera.Open((int)cameraType);
                camera.SetPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
                PrepareAndStartCamera();
            }
        }

        async void TakePhotoButtonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            camera.StopPreview();

            var image = textureView.Bitmap;

            try
            {
                var absolutePath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).AbsolutePath;
                var folderPath = absolutePath + "/Camera";
                var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderPath, string.Format("photo_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));

                var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
                await image.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 50, fileStream);
                fileStream.Close();
                image.Recycle();

                var intent = new Android.Content.Intent(Android.Content.Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
                var file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
                var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
                intent.SetData(uri);

                activity.SendBroadcast(intent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"               ", ex.Message);
            }

            camera.StartPreview();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I retrieve the views from the c# code using resource id, it is saying 'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for "view id" as screenshot below.

[image]

Why is that error throwing? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please make sure the three drawable resources did exists in your 
android project and then try rebuild.

Comment: I found the issue. Visual Studio is full of bugs when it comes to xamarin. The problem was because I copied pasted the xml. So the resources are not saved. Instead I had to type in the entire xml code by myself and so the resources are created. Terrible Xamarin and VS.